# Make a Strawpoll

Tags: code-golf, internet

> Moderator note: https://strawpoll.me has [officially shut down](https://support.fandom.com/hc/en-us/articles/7951865547671), and the linked API no longer appears to work or provide data. Therefore, new answers cannot actually do the task and so the challenge has been closed to prevent any new answers.

[Strawpolls](http://strawpoll.me/) are great, and we use them in chat all the time for getting opinions on things. But they're kinda annoying to make since you need a webbrowser to make them, and everyone knows that I access PPCG only through SE APIs and curl. So I want you to write some code that uses [Strawpoll's API](https://github.com/strawpoll/strawpoll/wiki/API) to make a strawpoll with the given options.

### Specs

Take as input a list in any reasonable format of options as strings, and a title which is also a string. Then use the API to make a strawpoll with that title and those options and output the url.

Multiples should not be allowed, duplicate checking should be enforced, and captchas should not be necessary.

## Example

```
"My Awesome Poll"
["option 1", "I like pies", "I also like cakes"]
```

Output: http://strawpoll.me/7275997

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in **bytes** wins!

Comment: (Just to help everyone) **TL;DR**: do this: `https://strawpoll.me/api/v2/polls{"title":"This is a test poll.","options":["Option #1","Option #2"],"multi": true}`

Comment: "**NOTE**: You must specify a "Content-Type: application/json" header in your request."

Comment: The API sort of doesn't work, or at least it doesn't work like the docs say it does

Comment: `https://strawpoll.me/api/v2/polls` always responds with http 400

Comment: Are you required to return the strawpoll in `http://`? Can I return in `https://` instead?

Comment: @KevinLau sure.

Comment: I can't get the API to respond properly with Factor or Python. @KevinLau have you tested yours?

Comment: I have, and it returns a correct response that I can use to get the strawpoll link.

Comment: I’ve closed this question because https://strawpoll.me has officially shut down, along with it's API, and so future answers to this are impossible

Answer (score 3):

## Factor, <s>257</s> 262 bytes

```
TUPLE: p title options dupcheck ;
[ command-line rest [ first ] [ rest ] bi "normal" p boa >json "https://strawpoll.me/api/v2/polls" <post-request> "application/json" "Content-Type" set-header http-request nip json> id>> 10 base> "http://strawpoll.me/" prepend ]
```

Expects a name as the first command-line arg, then options after that.

Requires `com-auto-use`.

Ungolfed:

```
TUPLE: poll
  title options dupcheck ;

: post-json ( post-data url -- response data )
  <post-request>
    "application/json" "Content-Type" set-header
  http-request ;

: strawpoll-main ( -- )
  command-line rest [ first ] [ rest ] bi "normal" poll boa
  >json "https://strawpoll.me/api/v2/polls" post-json nip
  json> id>> 10 base> "http://strawpoll.me/" prepend print ;
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby 2.2.4 + [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty): 129 bytes

Anonymous function; returns a string with the strawpoll URL. Remember to install the HTTParty gem before running.

```
->q,a{require'httparty';s="http%s://strawpoll.me/%s"
s%[p,HTTParty.post(s%[?s,"api/v2/polls"],body:{title:q,options:a},verify:p)["id"]]}
```

If the URL can be returned with `https://` instead of `http://`, 126 bytes:

```
->q,a{require'httparty';s="https://strawpoll.me/%s"
s%HTTParty.post(s%"api/v2/polls",body:{title:q,options:a},verify:p)["id"]}
```

Comment: Did you set the `Content-Type: application/json` header?

Comment: I got a proper response back, so I'd assume that HTTParty does that for me already.

Comment: This gem won't install, which is really annoying since I'd like to figure out why I keep getting HTTP 400.

Comment: What's your Ruby version? I updated mine to the version I have, and the gem says it needs 1.9.3+

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 145 bytes

```python
lambda t,o:post('https://api.strawpoll.com/v3/polls',json={"title":t,"poll_options":[{"value":x}for x in o]}).json()["url"]
from requests import*
```

A function which takes in a string for the title and *set* of strings for the options and returns the URL. I am not including an ATO/TIO link because you aren't able to do requests from those platforms.

In the intervening years since this question was asked, the original strawpoll API has become defunct, so I'm using [the newer API](https://strawpoll.com/docs/api/), which is unfortunately more verbose.